# Smart files combining for transfer

Tags: c#, .net, packaging

Have anyone any idea how make smart file combing without using any packager(Zip, Rar) only for transfer purpose.

What is my deal: I want transfer files package into mobile device, and unpackage it on them.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should put your files into an array, serialize them using the

```
BinaryFormatter
```

and transfer the resulting binary to the mobile device.